# SSL Configuration and then request redirect to JBOSS with httpd, modjk and openAM Fedlet for Single Sign On

Tags: ssl, httpd.conf, openam, jboss-eap-6, mod-jk

**SSL configurations are not working for httpd ModJk redirection to jboss Web Application that is integrated with OpenAM through fedlet saml2 approach for Single Sign On.**

Since i am doing this for the first time, i am requesting for some help on this.  I am trying to enable SSL configuration for Java web application that integrated with OpenAM(version 11) through fedlet saml2 approach for Single Sign On. SSL Configuration done and then request redirect to JBOSS with httpd, modjk and openAM Fedlet for Single Sign On. In OpenAM(version 11) server console, I generated the fedlet by configuring https application URL and used the same conf folder inside our application for communicating with openAM ldap authentication. When i hit the app URL in browser, request is redirecting to OpenAM for ldap authentication and after verifying LDAP credentials, it is not logging into application.

**Steps Followed:**

```
1   OpenAM deployed tomcat server is configured with SSL certificate using connector tag.
2   By accessing openAM console, created IDP server name (https://auth.test.app.com:443).
3   After that, i created fedlet in OpenAM for my web application by giving URL (https://auth.test.app.com:443/MyWebApplication)
4   Web Application is configured with conf folder of fedlet that was generated and deployed into jboss servers
5   openssl installed into apache httpd server and ssl configurations are made for ssl.conf,httpd.conf and modjk.conf files as specified in below (plz refer all configurations section provided below)
6   I am able to access app URL(https://auth.test.app.com/MyWebApplication/) in browser only when i did put entry into my local machine /etc/hosts/ file but i am doing all these changes in unix box server(I should access URL in public internet but Not sure if i miss anything i am not able to access until i register in my local machine hosts file. With http option, i am able to access without registering domain in my local machine hosts file, when try to configure https, URLs is not accessible until I register domain in local hosts file).
7   When i browse app URL https://auth.test.app.com/MyWebApplication/, It is redirecting to OpenAM server URL(https://auth.test.app.com/Signin/UI/Login) for ldap authentication. 
8   After entering ldap credentials in OpenAM login URL, THEN it is not logging into my application using https protocol, it is breaking and no logs observed. The whole process is working fine when using HTTP protocol but it is failing when trying to configure HTTPS.
```

**Process Flow Diagram:**

[Click Here To See Flow Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLXHO.png)

**Server Details:**

```
APP URLs       -->  https://auth.test.app.com/MyWebApplication/, https://auth.test.app.com
MOd jk server  -->  10.xx.xxx.143
OpenAM server  -->  10.xx.xxx.152 (openAM console can be accessed using URL https://auth.test.app.com)
Jboss_servers  -->  10.xx.xxx.111, 10.xx.xxx.222
```

**All Configuration Files**

```
##----SSL.conf------##
default values
-------
----
Listen 443 https
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName auth.test.app.com
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA
SSLCertificateFile "/etc/apache2/2.2/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/apache2/2.2/server.pem"
#My Web application using ajp protol
ProxyPass /* ajp://10.xx.xxx.111:443/MyWebApplication/
ProxyPassReverse /* ajp://10.xx.xxx.111:443/MyWebApplication/
<Proxy *>
AddDefaultCharset off
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
#mounting jk property file
JkMount /* worker
</VirtualHost>

##----httpd.conf--------##
default values
-------
----
IncludeOptional conf.d/SSL.conf

##------modjk.conf--------##
default values
-------
----
JkMountFile conf/UriWorkerMap.properties
JkWorkersFile /etc/httpd/conf/worker.properties
<Location /jkstatus/>
    JkMount statusmanager
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Location>

##----UriWorkerMap.proeperties---------##
#APP Load Balancer
/MyWebApplication=applb
/MyWebApplication/*=applb

#OpenAM Server
/Signin=Signlb
/Signin/*=Signlb

##----worker.properties-----------------##
#Log
workers.apache_log=/var/log/httpd
#Worker List
worker.list=applb,approute1,approute2,Signlb,status
worker.status.type=status
worker.approute1.type=lb
worker.approute1.sticky_session=True
worker.approute1.balance_workers=node1

#Jboss Node1
worker.node1.port=8009
worker.node1.host=10.xx.xxx.111
worker.node1.redirect=node2
worker.node1.type=ajp13
worker.node1.lbfactor=1

#Jboss Node 2
worker.approute2.type=lb
worker.approute2.sticky_session=True
worker.approute2.balance_workers=node2
worker.node2.port=8009
worker.node2.host=10.xx.xxx.222

#OpenAM Server Route
worker.node4.port=8009
worker.node4.host=10.xx.xxx.152
worker.node4.type=ajp13
worker.node4.lbfactor=1

worker.Signlb.type=lb
worker.Signlb.sticky_session=True
worker.Signlb.balance_workers=node4
                                                                                                                      


##----OpeanAM-Tomcat Connector----##
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
    disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="25"
    port="443" keystoreFile="/path/jksfile/keystorefile.jks" keystorePass="Password"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https"
    secure="true"  sslProtocol="TLS" redirectPort="8443"/>
    
##---JBOSS -connector--------------##
<connector name="https" protocol= "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
                        <ssl name="jboss7_ssl" password="Password" certificate-key-file="/path/jksfile/keystorefile.jks" protocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2"/>
</connector>
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? Is the SAML response sent back to the Fedlet (acting as SAML SP)?
General question: As both OpenAM and WebApp are hosted under the samle FQDN, why would you need to use SAML? SAML is a standards based web-based SSO protocol which does not rely on cookies, so is nice for cross domain access, but this is not your use case.

Comment: when i hit web app URL in browser, it is redirecting to openAM server and asking for credentials. when i entered the credentials, that request is not redirecting back to application logging. It is breaking there. All i need is that whether i configured SSL correctly or not without missing anything in the whole process that includes multiple sub flows modjk,openAM and jboss. I configured fedlet with https and used same conf folder integrating with openAM server.

Comment: openAM and webapp hosted into different servers . if the request goes from httpd to jboss below configuration is enough  , BUT in between OPENAM is there , i am not sure how to what configuration missing for openAM ssl (i configured openAM tomcat with ssl, fedlet generated with https , do i need to configure anything more?

Comment: > APP URLs -->  https://auth.test.app.com/MyWebApplication/
> openAM console can be accessed using URL https://auth.test.app.com

so same FQDN

Comment: How does the SP meta data look like you created for the Fedlet?
You need to check SAML trace. If OpenAM does not send a SAML Response it could  be an error with the SP meta data, but it's hard to tell without OpenAM logs and SAML trace

Comment: Issue has been resolved. I made wrong configurations. It is working as expected now. Anyhow, thank you for responding to post.